# Unable to resolve import mongodb driver for java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, jar, mongo-java

Trying to connect to MongoDB with Java in Eclipse.
I have downloaded the jar file

> mongodb-driver-3.8.0-beta3

I am able to import the com.mongodb.* package in eclipse for java perspective but its missing the com.mongodb.database & com.mongodb.credentials. I am getting an error as unable to resolve import.
Kindly help me fix this.

Sample Code below:

```
import com.mongodb.*;
class MongoJava{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MongoClient mc= new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb"); // Unresolved import                
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your actual code and errors here.

Comment: I think `MongoDatabase`  class file not available in the `mongodb-driver-3.8.0-beta3`
jar file. That is why you are unable to import it. You can use stable version 3.7.1 of mongo jar.   `MongoDatabase`   class is available in stable version. Source : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.1

Comment: For all versions you can refero official maven repository : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver

Comment: @Veeresh Thanks its resolved